# Looking for easy materials on Conformal Field Theory for beginners

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory

Question:
I'm a math student in senior year. I want to know about CFT(as the title explained). For related knowledge, I've learned basics about Differential Geometry, Differential manifolds. I want to just "touch", or get a sketch of this field, not to dive in for jargon and details. **Are there any books, or papers easy enough for me to understand?**

Why asking this:
I need to know CFT mainly because my Bachelor degree graduating paper, in which I'm supposed to get a basic understanding and a picture of modern math developments in Quantum Field Theory. CFT is an important branch in QFT so I must learn it briefly. But I have no background in QFT basics, nor in Quantum mechanics (I can learn them, though, given some time). So I came to ask if any of you know some material suitable for me.

Details that might help:
Below is a picture of Blumenhagen and Plauschinn 's Introduction to Conformal Field Theory With Applications to String Theory. The red-underlined equation, for example, is something I can't understand. What is $\varphi^*$ ? What is $g$ and $g'$ ? I'm thinking it may appears in some preliminary materials that I forgot or need to learn.

[The lines I don't understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjyIp.png)

Comment: $\varphi^*$ is the pullback, and $g$ in a metric on$M$, $g'$ is a metric on $M'$.  doubt this notation was introduced before, I think you were supposed to understand it from the context.

Comment: Thank you. Now I get it. I think maybe it's intended for physics students who often see the notation system. BTW, really, it's not introduced in the context which is why I think I may need some preliminary knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Francesco Philippe - "Conformal Field Theory" - classical book on 2-dimensional CFT.
David Simmons-Duffin - "The Conformal Bootstrap" - review of d-dimensional CFT.